# React Class Component not working properly for me

Tags: reactjs

I have a component of "Drawer", I am opening and closing this drawer with component state and passing this state down to the Drawer Component and Also passing a callback function that can help me to close the drawer,

Now the issue is that when ever I am trying to open that drawer, the whole ui is disappearing. Need help

here is the code

```
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Drawer from '../Drawer';
import Header from '../Header';
export default class LandingPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      openDrawer: false,
    };
  }
  handleDrawer = (state) => {
    this.setState({
      openDrawer: state,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='landing-page-container'>
        <div className='menu-btn'>
          <IconButton
            edge='start'
            color='inherit'
            aria-label='menu'
            onClick={() => this.handleDrawer(true)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
       
        <Drawer
          handleDrawer={this.handleDrawer}
          openDrawer={this.state.openDrawer}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is Drawer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Drawer,
  IconButton,
  Divider,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  Button,
  ListItemText,
  makeStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  ChevronLeft,
  NoteAdd,
  Person,
  PersonAdd,
  AttachMoney,
  Build,
  Settings,
} from '@material-ui/icons';

const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },

  drawerPaper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.primary,
  },
}));
export class DrawerMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes, openDrawer, handleDrawer } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className='drawer-container'>
        <Drawer
          variant='persistent'
          anchor='left'
          open={false}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
          }}
          backgroundColor='primary'
        >
          <div className='logo-icon'>
            <div className='logo'>Logo</div>
            <div className='collapse-icon'>
              <IconButton onClick={() => handleDrawer(false)}>
                <ChevronLeft />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <div className='drawer-menu-container'>
            <div className='drawer-menu'>
              <List>
                {[
                  'Booking',
                  'Positions',
                  'User Management',
                  'Trading',
                  'Instruments',
                ].map((text, index) => (
                  <ListItem button key={text}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                      {index === 0 && <NoteAdd />}
                      {index === 1 && <Person />}
                      {index === 2 && <PersonAdd />}
                      {index === 3 && <AttachMoney />}
                      {index === 4 && <Build />}
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={text} />
                  </ListItem>
                ))}
              </List>
              <Divider />
            </div>
            <div className='drawer-action-button'>
              <div className='setting-logout'>
                <div className='setting'>
                  <Settings />
                </div>
                <div className='logout'>
                  <Button variant='contained' color='primary'>
                    Logout
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(DrawerMenu);
```

Comment: Can you show me your `Drawer` component please?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: drawer component code is also added

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related to the fact that your `Drawer` is not on a `Fragment`. Try to modify your Drawer component code like:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'; //<-- import Fragment

...

export class DrawerMenu extends Component {
   render() {
     <div className='drawer-container'>
        <Fragment>
           <Drawer
              variant='persistent'
              anchor='left'
              open={false}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
              backgroundColor='primary'
           >
           ...
           </Drawer>
        </Fragment>
     </div>
   };
}
```

This should solve your problem.